# Ubuntu 16.10 phpmyadmin problem

Tags: apache2, mysql

Hello all i have problem with phpmyadmin localhost/phpmyadmin show while page no content my installation:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php5.6
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

I try everything but just not working.Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Does your apache server display pages correctly?

Comment: apache is good phpmyadnim not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same **problem** with my `phpmyadmin`on `Ubuntu Studio`. For some reason perhaps its a `bug` it refused to work.

My solution was to install it manually:

1. remove phpmyadmin
2. get it from the official site [here](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/)
3. unpack it into the apache root directory in `/var/www/html` and rename it phpmyadmin (or any other name you like)
4. access it from the browser at `localhost/phpmyadmin`

Hope it helps

Comment: please mark my answer as the accepted one, thanks glad to have been of help.

Comment: phpmyadmin in public folder is not that risky?

Comment: You can drop it in `/opt` and create a virtual host file in `Apache's `  sites available folder that points to it.

Comment: It works! To remove the previous installation use:  sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

**Installing phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety**

I finally got my setup installed and running after three days of struggling.
My localhost/phpmyadmin/ page was garbled and I could not enter the localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/ in the browser.

First I checked all locations where previous packages were installed:

> sudo find -iname phpmyadmin

The related files should only be in /etc/phpmyadmin and in /usr/share/phpmyadmin .

I decided to completely de-install all relevant packages including configuration settings and start over.

My steps:

To fulfill the requirements I used a softwaremanager (Synaptic) for easy install and auto updates.

I Installed latest versions of:

1. Apache2  (webserver)
2. Mysql-server (databaseserver)
3. php      (php: hypertext preprocessor)
4. php7.0-mysql (not sure if this was essential for installation)

And I installed:

5. phpMyAdmin   (in-Browser Database Management Tool based on php)

PhpMyAdmin uses its own database named 'phpMyAdmin'. 
Connecting to it requires a valid Mysql user. During the installation you are asked whether you want 'dbconfig-common' to create the database for you. In the same process it will create a User:**phpmyadmin** in the Mysql database. Tick the box to confirm and proceed. 
When asked enter a password for the user **phpmyadmin**.

After the install open a terminal-window and execute:

> sudo /usr/sbin/pma-configure

This will make the setup script writable (located in: /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php).
Note: You DO NOT need to create a config directory which is mentioned on some sites. That is required only for other distros than Ubuntu and Debian!

You DO need to update the 'htpasswd.setup' file in /etc/php/myadmin/ .
This step took me long time to figure out.
In a terminal-window type:

> sudo htpasswd /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup admin

Enter a password of your choice and confirm.
You need User:**admin** plus this password when you goto http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup .

You don't really have to make any changes in the setup for a simple installation.
After you are done save the configuration file (on Ubuntu 16.10 it is saved to  /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php )

Then secure the configuration file by executing:

> sudo /usr/sbin/pma-secure

(Essentially write protecting it with: chmod 0640 /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php)

Now you should be good to go: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
Enter your MYSQL Username: **phpmyadmin** and your password.

Goodluck.

I hope this helps.:-)

Answer (score 0):

The phpmyadmin package in ubuntu 16.10 does not place any files in default apache html directory. This would appear to be a bug, but the solution is simple. Just copy the files from the `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` directory.

```
cp -ar /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/
```

Comment: This should not be necessary. https://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/all/phpmyadmin/filelist showed me there are the two potentially relevant files /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf and /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/README.Debian.gz. First is very likely an example for linking/copying to the apache config dir

Answer (score 0):

I think install script have error, and you need to make manually load phpmyadmin config to apache2 and then reload it

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2.service
```

it's better to have phpmyadmin out of Docroot of Apache2.